# Fetching data from table using NHibernate that returning always empty

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to fetch data from EngineEvaluation table with NHibernate with the line :

```
using (ISession session = OpenSession())
            {               
                var c = session.QueryOver<EngineEvaluation>().List();                                 
                return c;
            }
```

but c is always empty though the table is not empty.

i mapping the table like this:

```
internal class EngineEvaluationMap : ClassMap<EngineEvaluation>
{
    public EngineEvaluationMap()
    {
        Table("EngineEvaluation");
        Id(evaluation => evaluation.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(evaluation => evaluation.EngineSessionId).Nullable();
        Map(evaluation => evaluation.Result).Nullable().Length(4001); // set length over 4000 to cause nvarchar (MAX)
        Map(evaluation => evaluation.Parameters).Nullable();
        Map(evaluation => evaluation.Score).Nullable();
        Map(evaluation => evaluation.IgnoreScore).Nullable();

        References(evaluation => evaluation.Engine).Not.Nullable();
        References(evaluation => evaluation.EngineVersion).Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(evaluation => evaluation.StatusChanges)
            .Component(component =>
            {
                component.Map(change => change.ParentId).Formula("EngineEvaluationId");
                component.Map(change => change.StatusChangeIndex).Formula("StatusChangeIndex");
                component.Map(change => change.Timestamp).Not.Nullable();
                component.Map(change => change.Status)
                    .CustomType<EnumStringType<EngineEvaluationStatus>>()
                    .Not.Nullable();
                component.Map(change => change.Details).Length(4001); // set length over 4000 to cause nvarchar (MAX)
            })
            .KeyColumn("EngineEvaluationId")
            .AsList(index => index.Column("StatusChangeIndex"))
            .Table("EngineEvaluationStatusChanges")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        HasMany(evaluation => evaluation.Errors)
            .Component(component =>
            {
                component.Map(comment => comment.Timestamp).Not.Nullable();
                component.Map(comment => comment.Message).Not.Nullable();
                component.Map(comment => comment.ErrorLevel).CustomType(typeof(ErrorLevel)).Not.Nullable();
            })
            .AsList(index => index.Column("ErrorIndex"))
            .Table("EngineEvaluationErrors")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

what can be the problem or how i can find the problem?

Comment: The connection string is pointed to the correct database?

Comment: output the generated sql

Comment: the connection is okay because other tables are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

By far the handiest tool to troubleshoot pretty much any NHibernate problem is NHibernate Profiler, maintained by a company that is run by one of the biggest NH contributors, Ayende.

You can find more info here: https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof

Answer (score 0):

I think that `EngineEvaluationMap` must be public, so it may be no being loaded. There's a known problem by which NHibernate silently ignores unmapped classes for QueryOver. What you can also do is enable logging so as to make sure you are issuing a SQL query.

Comment: Sure: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-querying-unmapped-classes.

Comment: Well no offense but you just linked to your own blog. I meant, could you link to other resources that backup such claim. If not, could you at least specify which versions of NHibernate would expose such behaviour. I know we're using the LINQ api extensively, I favor it for new development, and I'm pretty sure I clearly recall getting "MappingException"s when querying and something is wrong.

Comment: After doing some more research it appears NHibernate behaves this way when "hbm" mapping files are used. We always use Fluent NHibernate. Can you confirm or refute that hbm mappings must be used?

Comment: No offense taken, as I am a contributor to NHibernate an even wrote a book on it. By all means, do investigate on your own.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize you were a contributor or an author on NHibernate. My apologies for questioning you. Can you please explain why NHibernate silently fails when there are no mappings and in what versions it does so? I can't seem to find much about that topic.

Comment: But can you reproduce it - just create a dummy class and issue a QueryOver on it. Apologies for being so blunt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153248/discussion-between-mariods-and-ricardo-peres).